# How to prepare Workflow Manger Farm in DR for SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, disaster-recovery, workflow-manager-farm

I Prepared one SharePoint 2016 Farm with Two Servers
One WFE
One APP
In Application Server I installed & Configured Workflow Manager Farm and it created below databases 3 WF farm and 3 for Service Bus
WfManagementDB
WFInstanceManagementDB
WFResourceManagementDB

SbGatewayDatabase
SBContainer01
SBManagementDB

Now how to prepare same Workflow Manger Farm  in DR
I have one server in DR for Workflow Manger and we are using SQL Server Always On to sync databases between DC and DR

For DR WF farm can I do the same steps for installation Workflow Manger and Service Bus

Answer (score 0):

No, not the same steps.

If you were doing a true ‘cold standby’, then you need to install (**but not configure**) the SB/WF bits from Web Platform Installer.

For more information, please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/briangre/workflow-manager-1-0-refresh-disaster-recovery-further-explained#executing-the-failover-process

Comment: I installed Workflow Manger but did not configured it as mentioned and below databases also available in DR SQL,
but for configuration please can you provide steps and i did not found scripts mentioned in this article.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29158.workflow-manager-disaster-recovery.aspx